# Idiomatic way to count occurrences in a collection of Options

Tags: rust, idioms

I want to count number of occurrences of a value in a collection of Options.

```
let v = vec![Some(1), Some(1), Some(3), None];
v.iter()
 .filter(|Some(x)| x == &1)
 .count();
```

Doing this gives `refutable pattern not covered` error which makes sense.

I got around this by doing

```
v.iter()
 .filter(|x| x.is_some() && x.unwrap() == &1)
 .count()
```

What's the idiomatic way to do this in rust?

Comment: You were close: `.filter(|&x| x == Some(1))`

Comment: Do you want to count None ones also ?

Comment: sorry i chose a simplified example. My x is a struct and I need to compare it to a passed value in the rhs. Like `x.is_some() && x.unwrap().value() == id`

Comment: I don't care about the `None`s

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use `flatten` to get rid of `None` and unwrap the `Some(...)` values.

Code:

```
let one_count = v.iter().flatten().filter(|x| **x == 1).count();
```

To count `None` s you can simply use this:

```
let none_count = v.len() - v.iter().flatten().count();
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=10ebc428725ff19562326c5a9d638051)

**Why Flatten works for `Option`s ?**

From [@E_net4 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969723/idiomatic-way-to-count-occurrences-in-a-collection-of-options/55969946#comment98592882_55969946): Since `Option` implements `IntoIterator` it can behave like an empty iterator or iterator with a single element .

- Empty `Iterator` for `None`
- `Iterator` with single element for `Some(...)`

Comment: what does `flatten` on None return?

Comment: @pd176 removes the `None` values from the iterator, this behavior exist for `Option` Iterator. (Same for `Err` values of `Result` Iterator)

Comment: @pd176 `flatten` works here because an `Option` can behave like an iterator with either 0 or 1 element(s); it implements `IntoIterator`.

Comment: @E_net4 thanks, this is a better explanation, i’ll edit the answer  whenever i can.