# Simplest way to iterate over HashMap entry values in a safe and concise manner

Tags: rust

Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
let my_map: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
for v in my_map.get(&55).unwrap_or_else(|| &vec![]) {
    // v is a String
}
```

`my_map` may or may not have an entry with the specified key.

Is there a simpler (more concise) way to do that? If not, is there an equally simple alternative that would perform better, by avoiding empty vector initialization for example (in case LLVM doesn't optimize that)?

Comment: `for v in my_map.get(&55).into_iter().flatten()` ,[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=868422a9bc56bde5066a52dab5a2ccca), more info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55969723/idiomatic-way-to-count-occurrences-in-a-collection-of-options/55969946)

Comment: Ohhh that's nice. Making use of the fact that `Option<T>` implements `into_iter`

Comment: Thanks , Ömer! Exactly what I was looking for! :) Nice trick. Added it as an answer.

Comment: The empty vector should be negligible, as empty vectors are guaranteed not to allocate any memory. And while Ömer's code is nicer to read, it adds an extra level of indirection to every iteration, that may or may not impact performance. If you care about micro-optimization, always measure!

Comment: @rodrigo Useful comment! As always!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I was looking for (got it by Ömer's comment):

```
.into_iter().flatten()
```

And the complete example:

```
let my_map: HashMap<i32, Vec<String>> = HashMap::new();
for v in my_map.get(&55).into_iter().flatten() {
    // v is a String
}
```

Answer (score 3):

How about

```rust
if let Some(entry) = my_map.get(&55) {
   for v in entry {
   }
}
```

Comment: That's standard, but it adds two more lines of code and and an extra level of nesting.